# Wrap text around AsyncImage

Tags: ios, swiftui

I try to create View that wrap long text around AsyncImage but i got error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'AsyncImage' to expected argument type 'Text'" and "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Text' conform to 'StringProtocol'"
Is there a way to make it work?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
        Text(AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "myurl"))+Text("Hello"))
  }
}
```

Want to establish something like that:
[link for image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9zVL.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit confusing I am not sure what do you mean by

> I try to create View that wrap long text around AsyncImage

If you mean you want the text to be on next to the image, then just use `HStack` like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
        HStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "myurl"))
            Text("Hello")
        }
  }
}
```

You can also experiment with `VStack` and `ZStack` depending on what are you looking for. If you clarify the question maybe we can help better.